# Zoom before a "imfreehand"

Tags: matlab, image-processing, zooming

I am trying to measure the values of specific regions of an image in LAB colour space using imfreehand.

However, there are some sections that I would like to measure which are rather small; is there a way that I could zoom in to an image before performing the imfreehand ? Like how you zoom into an image to examine it in Matlab ?

Example of the problem:

[image]

What I have in mind:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with `input`. While the command line is waiting for an input, the user can still modify the figures at will (zoom, pan, etc.).

Here is a minimal exemple:

```
% --- Load and display sample image
rgb = imread('pears.png');
imshow(rgb);

input('');

% [ Press any key when you are ready ]

imfreehand
```

You can also use this trick to do a little command-line interface, which can be convenient sometimes. Here is a sample:

```
% --- Load and display sample image
rgb = imread('pears.png');
imshow(rgb);

% --- Main CLI loop
while true

    % Display
    clc
    fprintf('Please make a choice:\n');
    fprintf('\t[d] Draw freely\n');
    fprintf('\t[Other] Quit\n');

    c = input('?>', 's');
    switch (c)

        case 'd'
            imfreehand
            break;

        otherwise
            break;

    end
end
```

Of course, you can add more cases. This kind of interface is often very convenient and is a cheap alternative to developping GUIs.

Hope this helps,